# agrupar json segun datos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola Buenas espero estén bien tengo un problema el cual no puedo esolver. teniendo el siguiente json  quiero agrupar por **state* para luego crear uno nuevo ejemplo:

```js
  [{
    "area": "YUMBO",
    "state": "NOT"
  },
  {
    "area": "ZARZAL",
    "state": "VCAU"
  },
  {
    "area": "PUERTO CARRENO",
    "state": "VIC"
  },
  {
    "area": "SANTA ROSALIA",
    "state": "VIC"
  }
]
```

el cual deseo asi:

```js
[{"NOT":{"YUMBO"},
 "VCAU":{"ZARZAL"},
 "VIC":{"PUERTO CARRENO","SANTA ROSALIA"}
}]
```

[{
"NOT":{"YUMBO"},
"VCAU":{"ZARZAL"},
"VIC":{"PUERTO CARRENO","SANTA ROSALIA"}
}]

lo que tengo hasta el momento es esto donde creo un array donde almaceno los state sin repetir  pero no sabria como agregar la parte de area segun corresponda muchas gracias

```js
b=[]
c=[]
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if(b.includes(a[i].state)){
  }else{
    b.push(a[i].state);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que estuve viendo el JSON que queres como resultado no estaría siendo válido. Adjunto evidencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El siguiente código que hice provee un JSON válido con lo que queres

```
import json

lista=[{
    "area": "YUMBO",
    "state": "NOT"
  },
  {
    "area": "ZARZAL",
    "state": "VCAU"
  },
  {
    "area": "PUERTO CARRENO",
    "state": "VIC"
  },
  {
    "area": "SANTA ROSALIA",
    "state": "VIC"
  }
]
resultado=dict()
for index in range(len(lista)):
     if resultado.get(lista[index]["state"],None)==None:
                    resultado[lista[index]["state"]]=[]
     resultado[lista[index]["state"]].append(lista[index]["area"])
jsonarray = json.dumps(resultado)
print(jsonarray)
```

La salida en este caso sería:

{"NOT": ["YUMBO"], "VIC": ["PUERTO CARRENO", "SANTA ROSALIA"], "VCAU": ["ZARZAL"]}

La validación en este caso es OK

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias men por tu pronta respuesta

Comment: Si efectivamente me funciono para aclarar que tu respuesta es en lenguaje **Python3** por si alguna persona lo desea utilizar funciona bien Gracias

Comment: De nada!. Saludos y gracias a vos.